# $interval issue, ends unexpectedly

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs so this is probably simple. I have this as my main app entry point:

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Routed as such:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/general', { templateUrl: '/Rewards/SelfService_General', controller: 'GeneralController' })
    .when('/resources', { templateUrl: '/Rewards/SelfService_Resources', controller: 'ResourcesController' })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/general' });
```

My resources controller is as such:

```
appRoot.controller('ResourcesController', ['$scope', '$interval', '$http', function ($scope, $interval, $http) {

$scope.GetResources =  function GetResources() {
    var requestData = {
        AccessKey: "",
        Culture: ""
    };

    $http.post('http://myapi.com/etc', requestData)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.ViewName = status;
        alert('success');
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.ViewName = status;
        alert('error');            
    });

};       

$interval($scope.GetResources(), 5000);

}]);
```

On loading the page, the GetResources function is immediately called and as expected, hits the error function returning a 401 status. What surprises me is that no further calls to GetResources are made. Why is the interval ended?

Comment: attribute name should be `ng-click` not `ngclick`

Comment: Thanks @VinayK that sorted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$interval($scope.GetResources(), 5000);` should be `$interval($scope.GetResources, 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer to close the issue.

In your markup attribute name should be `ng-click` not `ngclick`.